# TSQL Rows to Columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have the following table structure

```
CREATE TABLE #T1
(
    UniqueID varchar(100),
    DrivingFld INT,
    ColumnFld varchar(10)
)
```

From this table, based on the DrivingFld field value, I would like the output of the ColumnFld to be in a different column. Min of DirvingFld's columnFld value should be in the first column or it should go the 2nd column.

We may have max of 2 rows or 1 row per UniqueID

```
INSERT INTO #T1 VALUES('1',1,'Val1')
INSERT INTO #T1 VALUES('1',2,'Val2')
INSERT INTO #T1 VALUES('2',5,'ValX1')
INSERT INTO #T1 VALUES('2',10,'ValY2')
INSERT INTO #T1 VALUES('3',5,'XVal1')
INSERT INTO #T1 VALUES('4',10,'XVal22')
INSERT INTO #T1 VALUES('4',5,Null)

SELECT * FROM #T1

--Expected Results
--UniqueID, Column1, Column2
--1 Val1 Val2
--2 ValX1 ValY2
--3 XVal1 Null
--4 Null XVal22
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways that you can rotate the data from rows into columns.

You can use an aggregate function with a `CASE` expression:

```
select uniqueid,
  max(case when rn = 1 then ColumnFld end) Col1,
  max(case when rn = 2 then ColumnFld end) Col2
from
(
  SELECT uniqueid, ColumnFld,
    row_number() over(partition by uniqueid
                      order by ColumnFld) rn
  FROM #T1
) d
group by uniqueid;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/13187)

Or if your database has the function, then can use the `PIVOT` function to get the result:

```
select uniqueid, Col1, Col2
from
(
  SELECT uniqueid, ColumnFld,
    'Col'+cast(row_number() over(partition by uniqueid
                                  order by ColumnFld) as varchar(10)) col
  FROM #T1
) d
pivot
(
  max(ColumnFld)
  for col in (Col1, Col2)
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/13186)